# How do I call the index (loc or row name) for an element located by iloc?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I have a dataframe called a.

I can select elements from the dataframe by position using .iloc.

e.g:

```
a.iloc[0,0]
```

What I need do is to call the row name or label (not the position), and store that label on a list.

If I use the code:

```
a.index
```

I can get the list of all the row labels in the whole dataframe. I just need to get the row label for a specific row, using its position. How do I get the label if I know the row's position?

This code:

```
a.iloc[0,0].index
```

is not working.

```
print(a[a['tpep_pickup_datetime']=='2015-01-01 00:35:38'].index.values)
```

the previous code allows me to call the index with a boolean expression, now I need to do that but with an element found by .iloc

Comment: Could you please be a bit clearer about what exactly do you want? And please format your question appropriately.

Comment: Yes. Does that work?

Comment: _"I can get the list of all the row labels in the whole dataframe. I just need to get the row label for a specific row, using its position."_ What do you mean by _position_? Do you mean the numerical position? Then do `a.index[i]`, with `i` the position?